# Trouble with diy wiring in basement room with afci and ceiling fan

Tags: basement, ceiling-fan, afci

So... I as a self/ Google taught electrician have wired in a room I have made in my basement with the following issues.

- The ceiling fan trips the afci breaker every time. It is fine with a normal breaker, trips with the afci; the guts are exposed to the fan and I have tried re- splicing the hot wires a hundred times to get better contact. The fan is also on one single light switch, no red wire.
- An unused treadmill is tripping the breaker on one of my outlets. The treadmill is fine on a properly wired in outlet, and I believe it's fine on a normal non afci breaker.
- I believe a power strip is also tripping the afci.

Comment: Perhaps best to start on the basics, why did you choose an AFCI breaker for this room?

Comment: It is code in our area.

Comment: that's a good reason

Comment: What make/model is the AFCI in question?

Comment: "D" Type hom115 cafi 120v; "also listed as afci".  It is longer than normal breakers...

Comment: All due respect, being "Google taught" is not effective and leads to faulty work. The problem is, Google answers questions, and you don't have enough baseline knowledge to **know which questions to ask**.  We've seen it 1000 times before where someone gets A and B perfect *and is completely blindsided by C and D*, because it never occurred to them to ask Google about C and D! How would they know?   **Get a proper book on DIY electrical work, genuinely read it cover to cover (within reason).**

Comment: Fair enough. I do have a basic background wiring simple outlets. I know how serious working out of the panel is and I appreciate it. And I did get a book titled: third edition "Wiring Complete" from Lowe's and along with checking all the pages regarding afci breakers I did read up on basic wiring. My ceiling fan reading tells me I need a separate hot wire (red) to run the circuit, but the youtube video that shows the exact same wiring setup for a fan with 1 light switch. I also installed a fan in my living room (wires were already ran).

Comment: Add pictures showing details of any box you added or modified. A diagram showing the overall wiring layout would be helpful if it's a large room, too

Answer (score 2):

One thing that will cause AFCI's to trip also happens to be something that will cause GFCI's to trip: crossed neutrals.

As you may know, all grounds are just basically a cloud of grounds - all grounds coming out of a panel can generally be mixed together, even if they are from different circuits out of that panel.   **Back in the day, people sometimes *thought the same thing of neutral*, which was never true.**  But it happens all the time where someone "grabs the nearest neutral" and that happens to be a neutral from a different circuit.  Or neutrals from 2 circuits have been tied together.  This mistake was undetectable; neutrals don't have breakers.

Now GFCIs and AFCIs don't like crossed neutrals, so it matters.

GFCI and AFCI will tolerate this situation as long as there is 0 load on the miswired part of the circuit (or both circuits if the neutrals are tied together on 2 circuits).  However when you add load, some or all of the neutral current "goes the wrong way". GFCI's are super sensitive to this, AFCIs less so, but will still trip.

Of course, it goes without saying that AFCIs don't work on *multi-wire branch circuits* (MWBC).  If in the panel, your AFCI "hot" is feeding up into a /3 cable with another hot fed from a different breaker, that is an MWBC. Safety requires you fix it: Get a 2-pole, 240V, handle-tied breaker, and land both hots on opposite sides of that breaker.  The AFCI versions of those are pricey.

So I would start by putting other loads on the outlets those devices are plugged into.  A 1500W heater should give a good test.   If the AFCI trips under those conditions, then it is a wiring problem and I would focus (in this priority)

- *multi-wire branch circuits* first, just because it's easy to cross off the list.
- crossed neutrals, as discussed, which means mapping the circuit, opening up every box in the circuit.
- any loose wire anywhere in the circuit, which would cause genuine arc faults. - converting backstab connections to either screw or screw-and-clamp, as backstabs are not as reliable, and sometimes cause genuine arc faults.

"re-splicing the same wire 100 times" won't do it. Re-splicing every wire in the circuit once is a better use of your time.

Otherwise the appliance may be generating an arc fault internally. Test that by wiring an AFCI direct to a single receptacle *only*, and plugging the appliance direct into that, and seeing if it trips.

P.S. are you actually landing the circuit neutral on the AFCI?  Or is it still going to the panel's neutral bar?

Comment: I've gone through and looked and the wires a few times and I have the outlets hanging out of the boxes (breaker off) but I will do it again. The neutral is going to the back bar. The model of afci gas only 1 recepticle for the hot wire.

Comment: Pop the AFCI off and look rather closely at it.  Is it [this breaker?](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/product/HOM115CAFI/miniature-circuit-breaker-120v-15a/) Look at "pic #3" which is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivitVu8KIBM), 20 seconds in.  If that isn't informative, plug other known-good into the circuit and see what happens.

Comment: That did it: I had both the neutral and the ground going to the buss bar. I also had zero pig tails going outlet to outlet. Thank you.

Comment: Double Pole DFCI Homeline is 82.00.... the same price as two single pole DFCI Homeline.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction to your problem is that your a picking up random arcs, but since you are saying that multiple pieces of equipment are tripping the AFCI, I'm thinking it may be a polarity problem. You need to go through your entire basement and make sure all of your lighting outlets and receptacles are connected white to white, black to black and grounds to grounds. You also might take a look at the length of the circuit itself the AFCI should not be further than 50' and could have an effect of the breaker. If you are over 50' you might want to install a normal breaker and move and AFCI device closer to the loads. See NEC Article 210.12 (A)(1)-(6).

Also when you say "the guts are exposed" are you talking aboout the AFCI breaker?

Good luck

Comment: The guts are the ceiling fan so I can look at the wires to the light and fan.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now you have experianced AFCI'S and there short comings, AFCI'S Can have problems with dimming circuits or variable speed fan controllers or modern washing machines, sowing machines any type of electronic speed or power controll. Even computer powersupplys. However you have a problem or two that may cause a real fault. , next limit to 1 question not 5,6,7...